# What is the name for this usage of delegate in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, delegates, closures

This is a terminology question.  In C#, I can do this:

```
delegate Stream StreamOpenerDelegate(String name);

void WorkMethod(StreamOpenerDelegate d)
{
    // ...
}

void Exec1()
{
    WorkMethod((x) =>
        {
            return File.OpenRead(x);
        });
}

void Exec2()
{
    StreamOpenerDelegate opener = (x) =>
        {
            return File.OpenRead(x);
        };

    WorkMethod(opener);
}
```

**Q1**
The Exec1() method demonstrates the use of an *anonymous delegate*, correct?

**Q2**
Inside Exec2(), would `opener` 
be considered an *anonymous delegate*?  It *does* have a name. If it's not an anonymous delegate, what should I call it?   Is there a name for this syntax? "named anonymous delegate?"   a local variable holding an anonymous delegate?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Q1: There's no such term as "anonymous delegate" (in the C# language specification) - but this uses a [*lambda expression*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) which is one kind of *anonymous function*. See section 7.14 of the C# language specification for details.

Q2: `opener` is a variable. The variable is assigned a value created using a lambda expression. After it's been created, the delegate is just an instance of `StreamOpenerDelegate`. In other words, the concepts of lambda expression, anonymous function and anonymous method are *source code* concepts rather than *execution time* concepts. The CLR doesn't care how you created the delegate.

By the way, both of your lambda expressions can be expressed more concisely - fewer parentheses etc:

```
void Exec1()
{
    WorkMethod(x => File.OpenRead(x));
}

void Exec2()
{
    StreamOpenerDelegate opener = x => File.OpenRead(x);
    WorkMethod(opener);
}
```

alternatively you could just use a *method group conversion*:

```
StreamOpenerDelegate opener = File.OpenRead;
```

Answer (score 10):

No and no.

**A1**: This feature is new to C# 3.0 and is called a *lambda expression*.  C# 2.0 has a similar feature called *anonymous methods*; for example:

```
button.Click += delegate {
    //code
};
```

**A2**: `opener` is a regular variable that happens to hold a lambda expression.

By the way, a lambda expression that takes exactly one parameter doesn't need parentheses.  Also, a lambda expression that consists only of a return statement doesn't need braces.

For example:

```
StreamOpenerDelegate opener = x => File.OpenRead(x);
```